# App crashes with IllegalStateException while requesting READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

I'm needing capture IMEI and IMSI of a device and how your already know, this requires a permission `"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"`. Happens that when rise this dialog window requesting this permission to user, my app is stopped. How solve it?

```java
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void ListarApps(View view) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {

    String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    String myDeviceProduct = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String myVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    System.out.println("Manufacturer: " + myDeviceProduct +
            " - Model: " + myDeviceModel + " - Android: " + myVersion);

    // Code For IMEI AND IMSI NUMBER ("android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE")

    final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 999;

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        
        
    String serviceName = Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;
    TelephonyManager m_telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(serviceName);
        
    String IMEI, IMSI;
        
    /*IMEI = m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    IMSI = m_telephonyManager.getSubscriberId();  

    System.out.println("IMEI: " + IMEI);
    System.out.println("IMSI: " + IMSI);*/
}
```

**Update** (logcat output):

> 12-24 15:31:43.787 27853-27853/com.testando.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.testando.teste, PID: 27853
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10141 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
> at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:4684)
> at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:866)
> at com.testando.teste.MainActivity.ListarApps(MainActivity.java:49)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

**Update 2** (AndroidManifest.xml file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testando.teste">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest.xml file ,Btw did you add permission in your manifest?

Comment: @JeffersonFarias where you  call  `m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();` ?

Comment: @Munir he didn't add permission in the manifest file.

Comment: @InziKhan Lolz..:)

Comment: @JeffersonFarias did you not add permission in manifest??

Comment: @Munir and InziKhan, i showed AndroidManifest.xml above. Question edited again!

Comment: @JeffersonFarias okay, then where you call `m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();`

Comment: @Munir, call to `m_telephonyManager.getDeviceId();` is: `System.out.println("IMEI: " + IMEI);`

Comment: @JeffersonFarias may you update full code ?\

Comment: Why did you add @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") annotation?

Comment: @Munir, `may you update full code ?` - is only show the result of String variables on logcat :-). I inserted it now on question.

Comment: @JeffersonFarias see my answer..:)

Comment: @Munir, i saw, but why `System.out.println` not is executed after conceded permission?

Comment: @Munir, ok already undertood. Is necessary insert `System.out.println` also on `onRequestPermissionsResult` method overrided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay as i understand your code you first need to check if permission granted or not then write code for `getDeviceId`

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // ask user permission 
} else {
    // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
}
```

You also need to override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```java
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // ask user permission 
        } else {
   // READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already been granted.
            TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            IMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();                    
        }
```